# which is the best way to merge two JSONObject(org.json) object in java

Tags: java

Need to know how to merge these two object

```
{"a":"1",
 "b":"2"
}

{"c":"4",
 "d":[{}]
}
```

To give
`{a,b,c,d}` with their values

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String...strings) throws JSONException {
        String s1 = "{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\"}";
        String s2 = "{\"c\":\"4\",\"d\":[{}]}";

        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(s1);
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(s2);

        Iterator itr = jsonObject2.keys();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            jsonObject1.put(key, jsonObject2.get(key));
        }

        System.out.println(jsonObject1.toString());

    }
```

Output : {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"4","d":[{}]}

Another way assuming you have simple JSON data as u have shown in the example

```
public static void main(String...strings) throws JSONException {
        String s1 = "{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\"}";
        String s2 = "{\"c\":\"4\",\"d\":[{}]}";

        int firstIndex = s2.indexOf("{");
        int lastIndex = s1.lastIndexOf("}");

        String result = s1.substring(0, lastIndex)+"," + s2.substring(firstIndex+1);        
        System.out.println(result);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

        Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Key :: "+key+" value :: "+jsonObject.get(key));         
        }       
    }
```

> output :: {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"4","d":[{}]} Key :: a value :: 1 Key
>   :: b value :: 2 Key :: c value :: 4 Key :: d value :: [{}]

Comment: without iterating the object

Comment: U must mention that in the question, you asked for the best possible way.

Comment: @ManiShankar I have updated the answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @ManiShankar will you Please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: @ManiShankar  if the solution helps you please accept and upvote the answer that will helps other to get the solution and helps me in gaining reputation.